# curl_setopt_array(): cannot represent a stream of type Output as a STDIO FILE*

Tags: laravel, xampp, guzzle

Error :

"message": "curl_setopt_array(): cannot represent a stream of type Output as a STDIO FILE*",
    "status_code": 500

System Info:
Windows 10 Xampp 3.2 php V 7.2

```
$response = $http->request('POST','http://localhost:8000/oauth/token',  [
'debug' => true,    
    'form_params' => [
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'client_id' => 3,
        'client_secret' => 'dddddd',
        'username' => 'ddddd@ssss.com',
        'password' => '123456',
        'scope' => '*',
    ],
]);
```

Comment: I have changed 
fopen('php://output', 'w'); to fopen('php://Memory', 'w');  but not working :(